# Getting hidden values and matching in jquery, javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a template that will consists of 2 hidden fields and 1 checkbox. The template is rendered and appended to the html page using a function `addProductImage()`.

How can I go about getting the value of the hidden fields (thisFile and mainImage)? The id of the div is dynamic `gc_photo_{{id}}_{{filename}}`, it look something like this **`gc_photo_1234_12dhbc.jpg`** .

After getting the value of the two hidden fields, I want to match the 2 values and see if it is ===, if is it will set the checkbox to checked.

Code for the template

```
    <script type="text/template" id="imageTemplate">
        <div class="row gc_photo" id="gc_photo_{{id}}_{{filename}}" style=" border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="hidden" name="thisFile" value="{{filename}}"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="mainImage" value="<?php echo $biz_product->image_name;?>"/>
                <input onclick="return set_parentimage(this);" type="radio" name="primary_image" id="{{id}}_{{filename}}" value="{{id}}" {{#primary}}checked="checked"{{/primary}} /> <?php echo lang('main_image');?>
            </div>
         </div>
    </script>
```

Code for the function

```
function addProductImage(val)
{
    view = {
        id:val.item_id.replace(/\s/g, ''),
        filename:val.detail_image_name,
        alt:val.alt,
        primary:val.primary,
        caption:val.caption
    }

    var output = Mustache.render(imageTemplate, view);

    $('#gc_photos').append(output);
    $('#gc_photos').sortable('refresh');

    thisFile = $($('#gc_photo_id_filename').find("input")[0]).val();
    mainImage = $($('#gc_photo_id_filename').find("input")[1]).val();


    alert(thisFile);
    alert(mainImage);
    if(thisFile === mainImage)
    {
       alert('true');
    }
    else
    {
       alert("different");
    }

       photos_sortable();
    }
}
```

Update 1
Code for the function

```
function addProductImage(val)
{
    view = {
        id:val.item_id.replace(/\s/g, ''),
        filename:val.detail_image_name,
        alt:val.alt,
        primary:val.primary,
        caption:val.caption
    }

    var output = Mustache.render(imageTemplate, view);

    $('#gc_photos').append(output);
    $('#gc_photos').sortable('refresh');

    thisFile = $($('#gc_photo_id_filename').find("input")[0]).val();
    mainImage = $($('#gc_photo_id_filename').find("input")[1]).val();


    alert(thisFile);
    alert(mainImage);
    if(thisFile === mainImage)
    {
       $('[name="primary_image"]').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else
    {
       alert("different");
    }

       photos_sortable();
    }
}
```

Comment: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
thisFile = $(output).find("[name='thisFile']").val();
mainFile = $(output).find("[name='mainFile']").val();
```

you can get values of thisFile and mainFile this way.

Comment: his problem was simply that hes trying to create multiple elements with the same name and id's.

Comment: creating multiple elements with same name is not a problem.

Comment: it is if they're in the same form

Comment: it is still not a problem. if you try serialize on a form you will see you get multiple values with the same name, doesn't matter if there are with [] or not. Now it depends on your server if it can handle those parameters or not. Where i work it is not problem. it automatically gets converted to array. though the point is they are same in javascript.

Comment: As the template is rendered dynamically, there could be more than 1 div generated.
And the name of each div is formed using this naming convention gc_photo_{{id}}_{{filename}}, it look something like this gc_photo_1234_12dhbc.jpg (1st div) while gc_photo_1234_ww45232c.jpg (2nd div). The {{filename}} will be the one that is changing.

Within each div, there is two hidden fields named thisFile and mainImage.

As such, I am trying to get the values of thisFile and mainImage within each div to compare it.

Comment: `id` and `filename` are variable i guess. which makes it different for div's as well. but yes in that case using script will not make any sense

Comment: hmm i guess youre right. my mistake. would be interested to know how to get them converted to array on post. would think that would be a browser thing rather than a server thing.

Comment: Can u all guide me in how I should go able changing the code to achieve it? @Sachin

Comment: Can u all guide me in how I should go able changing the code to achieve it? @Pamblam

Comment: browser gets the element by name.. doesn't matter if there are duplicate names. if there are multiple thisFile name, it will be like: thisFile=value1&thisFile=value2&thisFile=value3 so technically browser is doing his thing. Now it depends on how you get this values on server.

Comment: @benylim show us where are you rendering this template, that would be more relevant. because then we can get relative values from parent as well.